# How to unload a mode (e.g. unload ECB to restore winner.el functionality)

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I find ECB mode quite useful at times due to its souped up Speedbar and nice code browsing capabilities.  Unfortunately, I also heavily rely on winner mode, which is incompatible with ECB.  Even after I do `M-x ecb-deactivate`, all the ECB defuns appear loaded, and winner commands still throw an error about ECB/winner incompatibility.  Is there a way to remove the ECB definitions so that winner works as before, short of restarting Emacs?

Comment: What's the error message? Which version of ECB are you using?

Comment: This is ECB 2.40 running on Emacs 24.0.93
The error is `let: ECB 2.40 - Error: Can't use winner-mode functions in the ecb-frame.` I should point out that it /is/ specified in the docs that winner-mode cannot be used with ECB. However, I would expect winner-mode functionality to be restored if I turn ECB off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that ECB uses advice to display the error message ("Can't use winner-mode functions in the ecb-frame"), and this advice is not activated when `ecb-deactivate` is called.

I was able to work around this problem by disabling the advice in `ecb-deactivate-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'ecb-deactivate-hook 
      (lambda ()
         (ecb-disable-advices 'ecb-winman-not-supported-function-advices t)))
```

However, you should probably report this as a bug to the maintainers of ECB.